# Error 403 after rails capistrano deployment on apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

Deployed an app to a VPS running apache + passenger.
User:Group → rails:rails 
Deployed to /home/rails/www/appname

Here are the permissions on the files:  https://gist.github.com/2549332
Here are user groups: https://gist.github.com/2549336

But I continue getting a 403 error when trying to request the app.
The access log just sais Permission denied for /, nothing else.

What could be the problem and how to solve it.
OS running Fedora 14.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the virtualhost config:
https://gist.github.com/2550383

**UPDATE 2**

added Passenger_enabled to vhost

Passenger options in the httpd.conf are as follows

```
#Passenger for RubyOnRails apps
LoadModule passenger_module /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12
PassengerRuby /home/rails/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
```

Passenger processes, listed by ps:

```
root     32342  0.0  0.6 213928  1948 ?        Ssl  13:38   0:00 PassengerWatchdog
root     32345  0.0  0.7 288308  2208 ?        Sl   13:38   0:00 PassengerHelperAgent
root     32347  0.0  2.9 112704  8520 ?        Sl   13:38   0:00 Passenger spawn server                                                                                                                                              
nobody   32350  0.0  1.3 147996  3788 ?        Sl   13:38   0:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
```

**UPDATE 3**
Tried putting the standard Rails index.html in the public folder. No reaction.
Tried putting a plain index.html with just head and title, no changes either.

**UPDATE 4**

Even tried commenting out the Passenger lines in httpd.conf and restarting the server, and still I get the same error. Looks like it is something in Apache configs, but Ican't find what.

**UPDATE 5*
Renamed the vhost.conf to see how the server acts withought it, everything seems ok.

Comment: What user is apache running under?

Comment: apache:apache I suppose.
I did not configure anything when Iinstalled it, so it should be the default apache user.

Comment: Apache's user needs to have read & execute permission, me thinks...

Comment: According to the gist it does have read/execute permissions as it is in the rails group.

Comment: Needs to be the primary group, can you try changing ownership to `rails:apache`

Comment: tried it right now.
    `chown -R rails:apache temple`
nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Passenger doesn't hook up to your site and Apache decides to list the `public` directory instead, and directory listing is disabled in Apache.

- Are there Passenger processes visible in `ps`?
- Do you have [`PassengerRoot`](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerroot_lt_directory_gt) set correctly?
- Try adding `PassengerEnabled on` to the vhost config.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved by changing permissions for /home/rails directory so group could read and execute it. 
Thanks to everybody!